# Words repeating on stackexchange?

Tags: discussion

This is just something I keep noticing, just wondering why it happens.

Or if it's just my display somehow. Words repeat every now and then on the stackexcange site. For instance here:
[How do you get thumbnails to show up in the admin edit post?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/17826/how-do-you-get-thumbnails-to-show-up-in-the-admin-edit-post/17827#17827)

Here's a screen grab, in case it is just on my end

[image]

in my reply it says top right right

I used to think I was just being an idiot. But I see it semi-frequently. And not just in my answers.

Anybody else notice it or have a clue why it happens? Just a curiosity more than anything.... but I am taking a writing class, so things like that catch my eye lately.

Comment: i not see double words all looks fine on my end.

Comment: Same here, answer you linked to seems just fine to me.

Comment: No kidding? http://vudu.me/double Is what I see. Happens rather frequently.....

Comment: Double words can happen sometimes when you spend too much time time working on a computer. It happens to me me all the time time.  Wearing [Gunner optics](http://www.gunnars.com/technology/indoor.php) has helped my eye strain strain some.

Comment: Thats a good one Chris_O i suffer from this sometimes then i also swear i see questions that where there and are not really there at all

Comment: Seriously though this is a weird bug.  I only see 1 right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This [has been reported on Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92471/word-wrap-problem-in-answers-on-ie-7-and-ipad), so you are not alone. You might want to vote for the issue report there.

Comment: Done, thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

Internet Explorer 6 has a [bug where content is duplicated](http://www.impressivewebs.com/ie6-ghost-text-bug-with-multiple-solutions/). You should upgrade. :P

Comment: I'm on 7, not 6.... so it isn't that bad!!! I have no option to upgrade, I'm locked down at work. ON a quick google, it was an IE6 bug that was fixed for 7. Maybe it wasn't fixed? I've never seen it on another site except SE, that's why I found it so curious!

Answer (score 0):

This can happen in certain old browsers, but I have never seen it in newer browsers.